# Delphi SQLite database is locked

Tags: база-данных, delphi, sqlite, ado

Подскажите, пожалуйста (я не профи), как при использовании `SQLiteConnection` записывать данные в базу?

Отображать через `DBGrid` получается нормально. А вот как записать данные из Edit - не знаю. Пробовал так:

```
SQLDataSet1.CommandText:='INSERT INTO Workers (Name,Patronymic,Surname) VALUES (:Name,:Patr,:Surname);';
SQLDataSet1.ParamByName('Name').Value:=Name.Text;
SQLDataSet1.ParamByName('Patr').Value:=Patr.Text;
SQLDataSet1.ParamByName('Surname').Value:=Surname.Text;
SQLDataSet1.ExecSQL;
```

Вылетает

> database is locked

Где я косячу?

Comment: Может в дизайн-тайме в SQLiteConnection.Connected = True стоит?

Answer (score 1):

Работать в Delphi с SQLite, делая **такие** запросы через `TSQLDataSet`, - неудобно. В вашем случае ошибка из-за того, что вы не сменили `CommandType`, а именно:

```
SQLDataSet1.CommandType :=ctQuery;
```

Гораздо проще работать через TSQLQuery, например:

```
var
  Query:TSQLQuery;
  s:string;

<...>

s:='INSERT INTO `Workers` (`Name`,`Patronymic`,`Surname`) VALUES (' +
   '"' + Name.Text +'","' + Patr.Text + '","'+Surname.Text+'");';
Query.SQL.Clear;
Query.SQL.Add(s);
Query.ExecSQL;
```